# Div Previous Siblings is not reducing it's size

Tags: css

I have a code where div should increase its size to twice. It's working, but the previous siblings after hover are not increasing their size.

When I hover the first box, the rest of them change their size. When I hover the second box, the bottom boxes size changes but the first box doesn't change its size. I want to target the previous siblings too while hovering the box.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

.box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #FF7F50;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #6495ED;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #FFF8DC;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #DC143C;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #00FFFF;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #00008B;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #008B8B;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #B8860B;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #006400;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #B22222;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box10 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #E9967A;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box11 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #FF1493;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box12 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #9400D3;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box div:hover~* {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="box">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
  <div class="box5"></div>
  <div class="box6"></div>
  <div class="box7"></div>
  <div class="box8"></div>
  <div class="box9"></div>
  <div class="box10"></div>
  <div class="box11"></div>
  <div class="box12"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: There is no previous sibling selector (css is cascading - always flowing forward) - you would need js for this.  Otherwise just put the hover onto the parent - `.box:hover div {}`

Comment: This is my school project, did they give me the wrong assignment?  :(

Comment: On hovering the outer div, the who divs changing it's size now.

Comment: I mean the other divs*

Comment: Ok Thanks for help. Can i have a javascript refrence? how can i do that?

Comment: Pete check this . https://prnt.sc/lne6rq (third party website. But this is an simple screenshot)

Comment: I am doing point 3 right now.

Comment: Wow that's confusing - how can every other square grow, but then on the next line it says every square should shrink!

Comment: Pretty Confusing yeah :(

Comment: Do you know what I think it means only the hovered square should grow, but only every other hovered square something like `div:nth-child(odd):hover` but I could be completely wrong - but that's the only way I see it working with the next line of all the other divs shrinking

Comment: Maybe you are right. Project requirements typed mistyped. Isn't?

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Ok I think I have it half grow and half shrink when you hover so if you cannot put the hover on the parent, then you definitely need a bit of js for this just so when you hover an item, it adds a class to the parent where you can trigger the animations

Comment: This is how I see an answer to that question (missing off the add transitions to previous projects): http://jsfiddle.net/vst4c6xr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this. The trick is to target the parent div and expand all descendant but force the hovered element to not expand.

But you'll run into a different problem. When the boxes on top expand it pushes the box you are hovering over down and you lose the hover for that particular box. If it was something like a flip effect we would have no problem.

Check out the solution below and you'll know what am talking about. Hopefully you'll be able to figure out something for this. All the best.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 0.5s ease all;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #FF7F50;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #6495ED;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #FFF8DC;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box4 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #DC143C;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #00FFFF;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box5 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #00008B;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box6 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #008B8B;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box7 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #B8860B;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box8 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #006400;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box9 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #B22222;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box10 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #E9967A;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box11 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #FF1493;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box12 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background: #9400D3;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}

.box:hover>* {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box>*:hover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="box">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
  <div class="box5"></div>
  <div class="box6"></div>
  <div class="box7"></div>
  <div class="box8"></div>
  <div class="box9"></div>
  <div class="box10"></div>
  <div class="box11"></div>
  <div class="box12"></div>
</section>
```